# Kendo Grid resizable is not working in IE

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid to show the records.Below is my sample Html Page where i want to achieve the result for re-sizable in IE only. I have modified the code for Sample purpose only in Html. Resizable in Chrome is working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/column-resizing">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />


    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .wrap {
            width: 95%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .PageContentHeading {
            padding: 3% 0;
        }

            .PageContentHeading h3 {
                margin: 0;
            }

        .AddUser {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

            .AddUser a {
                border-radius: 0;
                padding: 4px 12px;
            }

        .btn-group-sm > .btn, .btn-sm {
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        .SupplierCompanyName {
            color: red;
        }

        .k-grid td {
            border-left: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>    

    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="toolBarTemplate">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="float:right;">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                        <input type="search" class="form-control" id='txtSearchString' placeholder="Search by User Details">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="main">

            <div class="PageContentHeading">

                <h3 class="pull-left">
                    Manage Users -
                    <span id="supplierPanel">
                        <span id="supplerCompany" class="SupplierCompanyName">
                            ABC Aerospace Inc.
                        </span> <span class="SupplierCompanyID">
                            [ ID_0001 ]
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </h3>

                <div class="pull-right AddUser">
                    <a href="@Url.Action(" AddUser", "user" )" class="btn btn-success" style="color:#FFF;">Add User</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right ShowUsers">
                    <span class="labelname">Include Inactive Users:</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="True" data-off="False" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-size="small">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>    
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        var apiUrl = "http://localhost:55020/";
        var dynamicTemplate;
        var col = [];

        function switchChange(e) {
            //alert('E');
        }

        function GetColumnsDetails() {

            var rowsTempldateStyle = "<tr>   <td style='word-wrap: break-word'>  <span class='UserDesignation'> #:FullName  #</span><span class='UserName'>#:title #</span> </td>  ";
            $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl + "api/user/GetColumns/1",
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            col.push({
                                field: result[i].colnameName,
                                title: result[i].titleName,

                            });
                        }                        
                        col.push({
                            title: "Active",
                            template: "<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' />",
                            width: "70px"
                        })
                        col.push({
                            title: "Action",
                            name: 'edit',                           
                            width: "70px"
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //
            GetColumnsDetails();
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    pageSize: 5,
                    batch: false, // enable batch editing - changes will be saved when the user clicks the "Save changes" button
                    transport: {
                        read: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                    },
                    pageSize: 20
                },

                height: 550,
                sortable: true,
                resizable: true,
                filterable: true,

                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 2
                },
                //resizable: true,
                columns: [{
                    template: "<div class='customer-photo'" +
                                    "style='background-image: url(../content/web/Customers/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg);'></div>" +
                                "<div class='customer-name'>#: ContactName #</div>",
                    field: "ContactName",
                    title: "Contact Name",
                    width: 240
                }, {
                    field: "ContactTitle",
                    title: "Contact Title"
                }, {
                    field: "CompanyName",
                    title: "Company Name"
                }, {
                    field: "Country",
                    width: 150
                }]

            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Latest version of Kendo but still it is not giving me the expected result. I have tried also to give the Width of each column but the same problem in IE. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: What "result" is this giving you in IE?

Comment: already mentioned in my "Subject" line of this problem

Comment: Right, but what exactly is happening? Is it just simply not giving you the option to resize the columns when you run this? Or is it giving you any kind of error?

Comment: there is no error but resize option is not coming in IE

Comment: Have you tried setting a width for each column? I see that two of your columns do not have a set width.

Comment: Yup...still didn't work

Comment: @Steve I had the same problem after having updated kendo. Please check my answer. I included a link with a you example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve please try to update to the new version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Here is your example working on IE now.

http://dojo.telerik.com/iKOKo/3

Kendo just released a fix to this problem on the 14th of july:

> AutoComplete widget inside Grid filter menu not expanding to full width
>
> Unable to create multi-page document
>
> Column resizing doesn't work in IE
>
> Undefined drag hint text when Grid column does not have title set
>
> Active filter icon is not visible enough

Check more details about this update here:
http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r2-2016-sp2